# Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0030: Cannot convert type

Tags: xml, class, xml-deserialization, xsd.exe

Identical symptoms to those in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678934/unable-to-generate-a-temporary-class-result-1-error-cs0030-cannot-convert-ty)

Basic symptoms are that when I use xsd.exe to create my C# class from my XML, when I attempt to deserialize it, I get this error (it compiles, but produces the error on runtime).

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).  Error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole[]' to 'ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole'

Original (from the .cs produced by (xsd.exe):

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("ServerRole", typeof(ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
public ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole[][] ServerRoles
{
    get { return this.serverRolesField; }
    set { this.serverRolesField = value; }
}
```

But following the advice from Ajax, I changed the following line
From:

```
public ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole[][] ServerRoles {
```

To:

```
public ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole[] ServerRoles {
```

This causes the following compilation errors:

> **Error**  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole[][]' to 'ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole[]' d:\Users...\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ReadingXMLDummy\ReadingXMLDummy\ProductEnvironment.cs    40  20  ReadingXMLDummy
>   **Error    2** Cannot implicitly convert type 'ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole[]' to 'ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole[][]' d:\Users...\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ReadingXMLDummy\ReadingXMLDummy\ProductEnvironment.cs    43  37  ReadingXMLDummy

Both being the inverse of the other.  I'm very confused and desperately need help :-)  Thanks in advance

PasteBin : [Program.cs](http://pastebin.com/43BEywm0)
PasteBin : [ProductEnvironment.cs](http://pastebin.com/zdrQLC7K)

Comment: Can you also post a link to some sample XML?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not in type being generated for property, but type in attribute for the property:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("ServerRole", typeof(ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
```

should be changed to

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("ServerRole", typeof(ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole[]), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the property and its backing field would need to be changed.  In your `ProductEnvironment.cs` you should also change this line:

```
private ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole[][] serverRolesField;
```

to read this:

```
private ProductEnvironmentServerRolesServerRole[] serverRolesField;
```

The error messages are the inverse of eachother because the property's `get` is trying to return your field (jagged array) as a single-dimension array, while the `set` is trying to assign a single-dimensioned array to the (jagged array) field.  (Line 40 is the get, line 43 is the set.)

You'd probably want to apply the same to your `Servers` property, too.

I'm not sure what would cause XSD.exe to generate such horrible code in the first place, though...