# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1)' SALESFORCE

Tags: c#, .net, salesforce

I am getting this error message while trying to run my web application written in C#

[image]

Code:

```
public SalesForceManager()
{
    SforceService = new SforceService();
}
```

Been searching for almost 2 hours and nothing seems to work for me.

Take a look, i found this:

[SIMILAR PROBLEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678934/unable-to-generate-a-temporary-class-result-1-error-cs0030-cannot-convert-ty)

but it did not work for me.

What is it happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by doing this:

1. Get the **reference.cs** file from my ASP.NET project
2. Find all the occurrences of **[][]**
3. REPLACE THEM with **[]**

Link to the website: [information](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83344/salesforce-wsdl-not-valid-any-more)