# Error: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1) ... When Invoking Methods on a Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, .net-framework-version

Error: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1) ... When Invoking Methods on a Web Service. I am using VS 2008 C# ASP.NET 3.5. I am invoking a remote webservice to my application.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Server was unable to process request. ---> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\6sbkwt2d.0.cs' could not be found
error CS2008: No inputs specified
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\6sbkwt2d.0.cs' could not be found
error CS2008: No inputs specified


Source Error: 

Line 775:        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/CheckLogin", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
Line 776:        public System.Data.DataSet CheckLogin(string uname, string pswd) {
Line 777:            object[] results = this.Invoke("CheckLogin", new object[] {
Line 778:                        uname,
Line 779:                        pswd});


 Source File:  c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\14127ae4\96323535\App_WebReferences.u9ldrmk1.0.cs    Line:  777
```

Comment: Could you please show us some code? How are you calling the web service? What is the webservices interface? Do you also have the code for the webservice function you're calling?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657993/system-invalidoperationexception-unable-to-generate-a-temporary-class-result-1)

Comment: @Wouter My webservice calling code is as follows-:              return objWEB.CheckLogin(username,password); I have included tha namespace using WebReference; and created webservice object (objWEB) WebReference.Service objWEB = new WebReference.Service();

Comment: @V4Vendetta Some says "You Need to give the permission to the temp folder which is in windows folder. And Your Problem is Solved...........".Temp folder of the system in which the webservice working or the temp folder od the system from which the webservice is called?

Comment: Did you try at the webservice level ?

Comment: Finally i got the solution.....

Comment: Please post the solution you found as an answer yo your own question: it might be helpful to others. You can even accept your own question, by the way.

Comment: Finally I got it.....It working fine

Comment: @DavidJohn: Add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 39):

First, credit where credit is due.  The OP solved this problem and answers it in the comments section of the question.  However, I understand that many people come to StackOverflow and will read through the question, and not look at the comments.  Therefore, I'm relaying the above answer here.  Be sure to up-vote the question if this is useful.

This problem occurs because the account that is associated with your web service's application pool in IIS does not have read/write permission to the `C:\Windows\Temp` folder.  I have no clue why the account needs access to this folder, but it does.  From my casual observation it looks like it just writes an empty file with a random name to the `Temp` folder.

To solve this problem browse to the `C:\Windows` folder, and right-click on the `Temp` folder.  Select **Properties**, and on the **Security tab** add the account associated with your web services application pool.  Hit the *OK* button, go to IIS and recycle your application pool.   This should fix your web service request.

It is worth noting that the circumstances around this error can be a bit deceptive.  I've ran into this problem a couple times over 5 years. (I've forgotten about it each time.)  The reason why it's not so noticeable is because you can publish a web service, successfully browse to the associated `asmx` page and see the outline of your web service methods.  Furthermore, your Visual Studio project can add a reference to the Web Service and Visual Studio will auto-generate all associated classes for the web service in your VS project.

This gives the impression that everything is working properly until you make your first request to execute a method on the web service.  The web service will fail when it begins executing code because it wants access to the `temp` directory.

Further information regarding this bug can be found at the acknowledged [bug report](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322886) at Microsoft.com.

Comment: Just an addition, we were working fine until we installed the Windows Management Framework 5.0 update and this started happening.  Possibly some permission changes?  Not sure.  Either way, your fix worked for us.  I added permissions for our service user.

Answer (score -1):

That happens when your web site doesn't work with Application Pool "DefaultAppPool" and you chose its own pool.
In that case you need to add an user with the name of your pool.