# Automatically Create XmlSerializer assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-serialization

**Duplicate:** This is duplicate of [Generating an Xml Serialization assembly as part of my build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134224/generating-an-xml-serialization-assembly-as-part-of-my-build). Please close it as a duplicate.

How do I get Visual Studio to create and embed an XmlSerializer assembly into an msi during a build?  I'm hoping to shave a couple of seconds off my app's startup time.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134224/generating-an-xml-serialization-assembly-as-part-of-my-build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generating an Xml Serialization assembly as part of my build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134224/generating-an-xml-serialization-assembly-as-part-of-my-build)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/d252d732-5e5b-480b-8280-285636da7db1/