# How to open a new independent form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'll start with a code:

```
private void button_newform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    Form newF = new Form();
    newF.show();
```

I have a form with a button who can open a new form.

the problem is, the new form have parent.

for example, if I'll click on `newform` button, it will create a new form.

but when I close this form, the new form will be closed too.

how to create an independent form, from an existing form?

Comment: looks similiar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049276/spawning-form-in-new-process

Answer (score 7):

The reason this is happening is because in the project->application properties, the shutdown mode is set to `When startup Form closes`. Change that to `When Last form closes`.

Comment: How do I approach these settings?

Comment: right click on your project, click on properties. you will find a Shutdown mode drop down list in the application tab.