# Why does the code compile a serialization assembly if I already created one?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-3.5, xml-serialization

My client-side code calls a old-school .asmx web service.  In an effort to boost the performance, I pre-generated serialization assemblies using the following command, that is run in the bin/release folder:

```
for %%a in (*.dll) do sgen /assembly:%%a
```

It essentially loops through all the .dll files and calls `sgen /assembly:foo.dll` on them.  After this command each assembly has a foo.XmlSerializers.dll assembly.

However, when I profile the code, I see that there is still a perf hit in the code and it still compiles a serialization assembly (completely ignoring my pre-generated one, as verified by ProcMon).

[image]

Why is it not using my pre-generated serialization assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

It tries to load the `.XmlSerializers.dll` file, but fails for some reason, and regenerates it instead. Possibly because it is out of sync with your assembly.

Try adding this to your `app.config` file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics> 
        <switches> 
            <add name="XmlSerialization.PregenEventLog" value="1" /> 
        </switches> 
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

This will make the generator print the errors it encounters to the Event Log.

More information: [XmlSerializers, ModuleVersionId, ILMerge, and You - Bits in Motion (blog)](http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/2009/11/xmlserializers-moduleversionid-ilmerge.html)

---

You might also be interested in this SO question: [Generating an Xml Serialization assembly as part of my build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134224/generating-an-xml-serialization-assembly-as-part-of-my-build)