# Serialization issue with XmlSerializer in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, enums

I have been trying to serialize an object which has an enum

```
 public EEEEEEE HandledAirlineCopyInd { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool RRRRRRR{ get; set; }
    [XmlElement("MatchInfo", typeof(TTTTTTTTT), Order = 11)]
    [XmlElement("MessageInfo", typeof(YYYYYYYYY), Order = 11)]
    public object Item { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public XXXXXXXX ModuleID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 5)]
```

The attribute ModuleId is an enum

```
[Serializable]
[GeneratedCode("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34283")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://VVVV/common/7/0")]
public enum XXXXXXXX 
{
    WM = 0,
    WT = 1,
    WI = 2,
}
```

when I am trying to serialize as below,

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = omitDeclaration;
        settings.Encoding = encoding;
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize, ns);
        string xmlString = encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        string xmlStringCleaned = CleanInvalidXmlChars(xmlString);
```

It is not serializing. please advise.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with what you have shown.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/mrBn2Z.  Can you add a [complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem including a full class definition and construction of an instance that crashes in serialization?

Comment: [Serializable]
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://xxx/common/7/0")]
    public enum WTR_LostPropertyRegisterRQModuleID
    {
        WM = 0,
        WT = 1,
        WI = 2,
    }

Comment: [Serializable]
    [DesignerCategory("code")]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://xxx/WTR_DelayedBagsCreateRQ/7/0")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public class WTR_DelayedBagsCreateRQ
 {
        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool HandledAirlineCopyIndSpecified { get; set; }
        
        [XmlAttribute]
        public WTR_LostPropertyRegisterRQModuleID ModuleID { get; set; }
       
        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool TracingOptionSpecified { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Still not sure I see your problem - I can serialize your class without an exception getting thrown.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/JXGFSW.  Can you edit your question to explain what you mean by *It is not serializing*?

Comment: In my serialized xml ModuleId is not there. I can see your example perfectly fine but in my application ModuleId is not included in the xml.

Comment: What does `CleanInvalidXmlChars` do?  Could that be causing a problem?

Comment: private static string CleanInvalidXmlChars(string text)
        {
            string re = @"[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-x10FFFF]";
            return Regex.Replace(text, re, "");
        }

Comment: Make sure you don't have any out-of-date pre-generated XmlSerializer assemblies.  For background see [Boost performance with Pre-generated XmlSerializers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2009/02/02/boost-performance-with-pre-generated-xmlserializers/) and [XML Serializer Generator Tool (Sgen.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240.aspx) and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134224/generating-an-xml-serialization-assembly-as-part-of-my-build