# Visual studio doesn't let compile "Sgen could not be run"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sgen

Getting the error:

```
"The specified task executable "sgen.exe" could not be run. The filename or extension is too long F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   3408"
```

And Warning:

```
"The command-line for the "SGen" task is too long. Command-lines longer than 32000 characters are likely to fail. Try reducing the length of the command-line by breaking down the call to "SGen" into multiple calls with fewer parameters per call.   DAYAnalytics    F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 3408"
```

At this part of Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets :

```
<SGen
    BuildAssemblyName="$(TargetFileName)"
    BuildAssemblyPath="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
    References="@(ReferencePath)"
    ShouldGenerateSerializer="$(SGenShouldGenerateSerializer)"
    UseProxyTypes="$(SGenUseProxyTypes)"
    UseKeep="$(SGenUseKeep)"
    KeyContainer="$(KeyContainerName)"
    KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)"
    DelaySign="$(DelaySign)"
    ToolPath="$(SGenToolPath)"
    SdkToolsPath="$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)"
    EnvironmentVariables="$(SGenEnvironment)"
    MSBuildArchitecture="$(SGenMSBuildArchitecture)"
    SerializationAssembly="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(_SGenDllName)"
    Platform="$(SGenPlatformTarget)"
    Types="$(SGenSerializationTypes)">
```

The explanation is pretty straightforward, But I don't understand how to fix it.
How do I reduce the command line length?

Answer (score 1):

Set the "Generate serialization assembly" option in the Build options to "Auto" or "Off", unless you need them (that is, you make extensive use of the XmlSerializer), in which case you'll find more info here: [Generating an Xml Serialization assembly as part of my build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134224/generating-an-xml-serialization-assembly-as-part-of-my-build)