# Can't Build Project In Visual Studio 2022 Due To XmlSerialization (sgen.exe) And Can't Disable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, sgen.exe

I'm getting this error when I compile my project written in VS 2019 in dotnet which I've just migrated to dotnet core 6.0 and loaded into VS 2022.

```
Error   MSB6003 The specified task executable "sgen.exe" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The filename or extension is too long
```

There appears to be a known issue with XmlSerialization failing due to long filenames. Fixes include turning off [Generate Serialization assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199538/msb6003-the-specified-task-executable-sgen-exe-could-not-be-run-the-filename) and the official MS fix of enabling long filenames [since at least 2017](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2017-153-error-the-specified-task-executable-sg/98090).

Disabling XmlSerialization should be possible from the UI in VS 2019, and should be possible in the project file by adding:

```
<GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
```

However, there is no option in VS 2022 to do this through the UI, and the config above seems to be ignored. As such I can't see how to avoid the error in VS 2022. I've tried disabling it in the VS 2019 and loading in VS 2022, but that doesn't work.

Update: I also tried moving the solution to a dir on root with a 2 char name. No joy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried disabling in the project file again, and it worked this time.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
   ...
   <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

VS 2022 doesn't seem to have the UI option like VS 2019 so you seem to have to do this manually.

I'm getting now a

> `The command "copy "\policy.xml" "" " exited with code 1 error`

but that's a different problem...