# Why does Visual Studio generate a MyProject.XmlSerializers.dll?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, .net-4.7.2

I have a C# Class Library project targeting .NET FW 4.7.2.
Every time I compile the project, it also generates a file `MyProject.XmlSerializers.dll`.
I'm pretty sure this is ok and it is needed for XML serialization. But I want to know why it creates it and if there is some project setting to adjust this.

Comment: Those are [Microsoft XML Serializer Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/xml-serializer-generator) assemblies a.k.a [`Sgen.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-serializer-generator-tool-sgen-exe) assemblies that might have or might not been created at the time the project was built.  See [Generating an Xml Serialization assembly as part of my build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134224) for a discussion of how they are enabled (and disabled).

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, "Generate serialization assembly" = Off.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dbc & HansPassant. Both comments help.

Turning Project > Properties > Build tab, "Generate serialization assembly" off skips the Sgen.exe during the build process. Turning it On or Auto enables it. Sgen.exe is the part that generates the serialization assembly.